# How do I get the wavelength of light from a diffraction experiment using Python?

Tags: python, quantum-mechanics, experimental, soft-question, diffraction

What is the procedure after using a diffraction grating (device used to see the spectrum) using python? We would see the entire electromagnetic spectrum emitted by an object but what then? how do I measure the wavelength of the light using Python?

I am expecting the diffraction grating to project the entire spectrum of the an object (probably through an magnifying glass) to an camera, then I want the data from the camera to be analyzed, then the script to show the wavelength of the light emitted

I suspect that OpenCV might be used

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm going to close the question for now, since it seems like the discussion in chat has led to posting smaller subquestions on other sites. But if you think that there is still a subquestion that fits here, feel free to edit this post and I can reopen it.

Comment: Thanks, @Tyberius

Comment: This conversation was moved to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62781959#62781959).